# Data do not delete in mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, mongodb

My js code:

```
$scope.del = function (record) {
        if (confirm('Do you really want to delete?')){
             $http['delete']('/camera/list/' + record.filename).then(function() {
            $scope.records.splice($scope.records.indexOf(record), 1);
          });
        }
      };
```

My html code:

```
<td><button class="btn" ng-click="del(record)">Delete</button></td>
```

My controller:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/list/{fn}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
  public ResponseEntity<Record> deleteUser(@PathVariable("fn") String filename) {
   System.out.println("Fetching & Deleting data " + filename);

   Record user1 = rep.findByfilename(filename);
   if (user1 == null) {
       System.out.println("Unable to delete. " + filename + " not found");
       return new ResponseEntity<Record>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
   }

   rep.deleteUserById(filename);
   return new ResponseEntity<Record>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
}
```

I created a delete controller but it still does not remove the data on my mongodb and only able to remove the data on my gui itself. Anybody can help me see what i do wrong? As i do not have any error.

Comment: Should it be something like `rep.deleteUserById(user1._id)`?

Comment: But I delete by filename instead of _id

Comment: Then can you use `rep.deleteUserByFilename`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills No different..

Comment: Did you try plugging in you debugger to figure out what *exactly* happens, line after line? If you determined that the front-end AJAX call hits the server there's no point posting that code in your question over and over again. It's clear you're stabbing in the dark. It would be also useful to see the definition of your repository.

Comment: @kryger I solved thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try to test a bit more to know exactly where that come from.

If the request work but delete just parts of data it can be a problem in rights for your API user.

That is 2 years i havent work with mongo so i might be outdated but if its not the rights, then you could try to do that an other way, for exemple instead of handling it only from your web page try to create a local script that you execute alone on side.

I hope that can help you.

Comment: I tried postman and is able to delete the data but not in the mongodb.